# Add switch button thumb tint color programmaically (ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<Switch
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:thumbTint="@color/red"/>
```

I want to add red thumb tint color to my switch in java

Below is my code in java

```
Switch switch_btn=new Switch(edit_turf.this);
              switch_btn.setOnClickListener(edit_turf.this)
              switch_btn.setId(i);
              relativeLayout.addView(switch_btn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can use:

```
switch.setThumbTintList(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this,R.color.xxxx));
```